# express TSOA + passport

Tags: express, passport.js, tsoa

I'm trying to migrate a custom based controller API based on express to TSOA framework.
I was using **passport** to handle authentication before.

How can I use it with TSOA? It seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need just to add `app.use(passport.authenticate('jwt'));` above `RegisterRoutes(app);` in your (propbaly) `server.ts` file.

Like this:

```js
// ...
// passport.use('jwt',new JWTStrategy({<your_data_here>}));
// passport.initialize();
app.use(passport.authenticate('jwt'));
RegisterRoutes(app);
// ...
// const httpServer = createServer(app);
// httpServer.listen(82811, () => {
//   console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:82811`);
// });
```